# Traduction d'un texte religieux

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, religion

## tl;dr

Je voudrais confirmer / corriger ma traduction d'un texte formel et
religieux, qui suit dessous. Est-ce que j'en ai bien capté le sens et la
formalité ? Les choix de mots (« *présence, puissance, dons, conseil* »)
m'inquiètent particulièrement.

#### Text in English

> We are ready and waiting.
>
> We long for your presence and power.
>
> Bring your gifts and your guidance.
>
> Come, Holy Spirit, Come.

#### Tentative en Français

> Nous attendons, nous sommes prêts.
>
> Nous désirons ta présence et ta puissance.
>
> Apporte tes dons et ton conseil.
>
> Viens, saint Esprit, viens.

### Contexte

Je viens de rentrer aux États-Unis après de passer 4 mois en France en étudiant
la langue, la littérature, et l'histoire.

À mon temple, on me demande si je pourrais participer à une Pentecôte unique--on
souhaite entendre d'autres langues que seulement l'Anglais, le Français y
compris.

Alors, à moi de traduire ces quatre phrases-là, qui serviront comme introduction
dimanche matin.

*N.B.* Il faut imprimer les dépliants mercredi, alors toute rapidité sera utile
!

Comment: À mon sens il faudrait dire « apporte-nous » (ou « aux hommes » ou un tel bénéficiare). À part ça les traductions semblent être correctes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour ma part, je traduirais ainsi :

> Nous sommes prêts et T'attendons.
>
> Nous désirons Ta présence et Ta puissance.
>
> Apporte-nous Tes dons et Tes conseils.
>
> Viens, Saint-Esprit, viens.

Comment: Doh ! J’avais oublié les majuscules !

Comment: Bien que ce soit accepté (mais pas obligatoire) dans les textes religieux, ce qui est bien le cas ici, ne pas mettre de majuscule aux pronoms et adjectifs possessifs se référant à Dieu est la règle en orthographe française.

Comment: @jlliagre noté.

Answer (score 2):

If related to the Trinity, that should be *Saint-Esprit*, not *saint Esprit*. I concur with Luke about *apporte-nous*.